# how to add verification code in a form?

Tags: php

i am new in php, i have a php form containing search box which will search the genes from my database. But there is a need to add verification code before access. i don't know how to add verification code for e.g. image will appear with some numbers or alphabets which user have to type for further processing.

the code for creating form is following:

```
<form method="post" action="test3.php" name="search_form">
   <p align="right"><input type="text" name="search" size=15 maxlength=15 placeholder = "Gene Symbol">
    <select name="table[]" size = "0" multiple>
    <option selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="infla_info">Inflammation</option>
    <option value="diet_info">diet</option>
    <option value="obesity_info">obesity</option>
    <option value="stress_info">stress</option>
    <option value="atherosclerosis_info">atherosclerosis</option>
    <option value="retinopathy_info">Diabetic Retinopathy</option>
    <option value="nephropathy_info">Diabetic Nephropathy</option>
    <option value="neuropathy_info">Diabetic Neuropathy</option>
    </select>
    <input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Gene Search">
    </p>
    </form>
```

please help me !

Comment: Try to add `Captcha`.See this http://www.9lessons.info/2011/01/php-captcha-code.html once

Comment: It's called 'captcha', there are plenty of ready-made solutions out there (like reCaptcha)

Comment: The purpose of this site is to come with specific coding problems. In this case, you need to try something and come back with specific problems you are having.  There are plenty of examples on the internet to do what you want to do.

Comment: CAPTCHA is a generic term for an image that contains a randomly generated string that is visually scrambled but still legible for humans. Google it, the best way for you would be to find a tutorial or plugin and use that instead of making your own. If you want to make your own however, you'll need to look at the GD lib in PHP (and again, a CAPTCHA tutorial would help).

Comment: i know robert, but as i told u m new here i was not getting the correct use of captcha from other site, basically wasn't able to understand how to add in my code so that y i asked here..

Comment: @jyoti so you should post your non-working code and get help in _fixing_ it, not ask for someone to provide you with a working one

Answer (score 2):

**[reCAPTCHA](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/php)** is a good choice.

**Client**

```
<?php
require_once('/path/to/recaptchalib.php');

$publickey = "your_public_key"; // you got this from the signup page
$recaptcha = recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
?>

<form method="post" action="test3.php" name="search_form">
    <p align="right">
        <input type="text" name="search" size=15 maxlength=15 placeholder = "Gene Symbol"/>
        <select name="table[]" size = "0" multiple>
            <option selected="selected"></option>
            <option value="infla_info">Inflammation</option>
            <option value="diet_info">diet</option>
            <option value="obesity_info">obesity</option>
            <option value="stress_info">stress</option>
            <option value="atherosclerosis_info">atherosclerosis</option>
            <option value="retinopathy_info">Diabetic Retinopathy</option>
            <option value="nephropathy_info">Diabetic Nephropathy</option>
            <option value="neuropathy_info">Diabetic Neuropathy</option>
        </select>

        <?php echo $recaptcha; ?>

        <input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Gene Search"/>
    </p>
</form>
```

**Server**

```
<?php
require_once('/path/to/recaptchalib.php');
$privatekey = "your_private_key";
$resp       = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                      $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                      $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                      $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

if (!$resp->is_valid) {
    // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
    die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again." . "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");
} else {
    // Your code here to handle a successful verification
}
?>
```

Comment: hello wahyu can you tell where to add this server php file in the form as in form action test3.php is there

Comment: Yes! `test3.php` is your server and also form action. Server is where your data will be processed.

Comment: you mean i have to add this server code in test3.php

Comment: Ya.. Server code for `test3.php`.

Comment: but this test3.php is for different purpose,, i mean it is used to fetch other information related to gene.

Comment: this code i have given here is for searching given gene from the database. but after this i want a verification code i.e. after entering gene name user has to type the verification code appearing in the image if code true search will be done otherwise sorry mesaage.

Comment: You have to understand how the captcha processed. In essence, after request from the form, then before being processed, you must process  captcha. `if ($resp->is_valid)` go to form processing.